# Swift: How to stop timers started from a loop?

Tags: ios, swift

I got some Swift code to print every character of a specific word `("stackoverflow")` and also with a specific delay `(1.0s)`.

---

To understand my thoughts look at the pseudo code:

```
print("s")
wait(1s)
print("t")
wait(1s)
print("a")
wait(1s)
print("c")
wait(1s)
print("k")
wait(1s)
...
```

---

Ok - below you can find my code written in Swift:

```
var mystring="stackoverflow"
var counter=0.0

for i in mystring {
  Timer.scheduledTimer(
     timeInterval: Double(counter),
     target: self,
     selector: #selector(self.myfunc(_:)),
     userInfo: String(i),
     repeats: false)
     counter=counter+1.0
   })
}
```

---

```
func myfunc(_ timer: Timer) {
    let value: String? = timer.userInfo! as? String
    print ("Value: \(value as String?)")
}
```

But how is it possible to kill all `myfunc`-calls after the for loop has finished? **How to kill the different Timers that I didn't declared with a variable to avoid the override of the last Timer**??

Comment: have an array of timers, and then stop them with index.

Comment: Could you please give me some code snippets about your thoughts? @NikhilManapure

Comment: You've accepted the wrong answer. You only want one timer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit : For those who argue that this is not the best answer it's the best for his current programming technique and to suggest a good one here is a solution in edit part for his main issue with no timers at all

Edit://////

```
var counter = 0.0

for i in mystring {

 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + counter) {

  print("\(String(i))")

  }

 counter = counter + 1

}
```

/////////

declare var

```
  var timerarr = [Timer] = []
```

then add every created timer to the array

```
  for i in mystring {
      let t = Timer.scheduledTimer(
      timeInterval: Double(counter),
      target: self,
      selector: #selector(self.myfunc(_:)),
      userInfo: String(i),
      repeats: false)
      counter=counter+1.0     
      })
      timerarr.append(t)
   }
```

and loop to stop

```
 for i in 0..<timerarr.count {
    let tim = timerarr[i]
    tim.invalidate()  
 }

 timearr = []
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for his solution I'm not here to suggest a good programming approach , but if i do edit will be with no timers

Answer (score 2):

Why not **one** timer and a few lines additional logic. The code prints the first character of the string when the timer fires and then drops the first character until the string is empty. At the end the timer gets invalidated.

```
let string = "stackoverflow"

var temp = Substring(string)
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    print(temp.prefix(1))
    temp = temp.dropFirst()
    if temp.isEmpty { timer.invalidate() }
}
```

or as ticker

```
let string = "stackoverflow"

var counter = 1
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    print(string.prefix(counter))
    if counter == string.count  { timer.invalidate() }
    counter += 1
}
```